# Assessing your own classifier function with ClassifierMeasurements or NetMeasurements

Tags: probability-or-statistics, machine-learning

The functions `ClassifierMeasurements` and `NetMeasurements` expect objects that are created through `Classify` or are objects with head `NetGraph`, `NetChain` etc.

I've got a classifier that I've created through my own algorithm and I would like to use `ClassifierMeasurements` to easily get assessment tools like confusion matrix, ROC, and all the other statistics that `ClassifierMeasurements` can compute. However, if I provide my function to `ClassifierMeasurements`, it complains that my function is not an adequate classifier object.

The only solution that I can see right now, is to find a third party implementation or implement the statistics that I need by myself.

My question is:
Is there a way to wrap my classifier such that `ClassifierMeasurements` would work with it?

PS: Of course, I could adapt my classifier that it either gives a probability vector, or the class index or anything else as output.